# Time for particle to fall to Earth

Tags: integration, classical-mechanics

I have seen the time quoted for a particle to fall to Earth from a height h (variations of gravity are taken into account) as

$\sqrt{\frac{2h}{g}}\left(1+
\frac{5h}{6R}\right)$

where R is the radius of the Earth. Having set up the equation of motion with g factored for a height of h, this solution still evades me. Can any one shed some light on this result ?

Comment: Is $h$ counted from the ground level or center of the Earth ?

Comment: Height is above the surface of the Earth I would say

Comment: What are your equations of motion?

Comment: This is now bothering me whether it is correct or not.

Comment: $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -g\frac{r^2}{(r+h)^2$

Comment: ...apologies, my Tex experience is limited

Comment: You forgot the last closing brace: $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -g\frac{r^2}{(r+h)^2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to expand on @YvesDaoust's answer (including the label change from $h$ to $h_0$), the substitution $x:=\sqrt{\frac{R+h}{h_0-h}}$ and abbreviation $y:=\frac{h_0}{R}$ gives the time as $$t=\frac{(R+h_0)^{3/2}}{R\sqrt{2g}}\int_{R/h_0}^\infty\frac{\sqrt{x}dx}{(x+1)^2}=\sqrt{\frac{h_0}{2g}}(1+y)^{3/2}\left[\frac{1}{1+y}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}\arctan\sqrt{y}\right].$$Since $y$ is small, $$t=\sqrt{\frac{h_0}{2g}}\left(1+\frac32 y+o(y)\right)\left(1-y+1-\frac13 y+o(y)\right)=\sqrt{\frac{2h_0}{g}}\left(1+\frac56 y\right).$$

Comment: Well, but if $y$ is small, what's the point of taking variations in gravity into account? According to your calculations, the formula given in the OP is wrong for general $y$, right?

Comment: @TonyK If we neglect variations altogether, we get $t=\sqrt{\frac{2h_0}{g}}$. Since $y$ is nonzero, but small outside of space travel, it's useful to expand $t$ at lowest-order, i.e. to get the $O(y)$ term. The OP's equation wouldn't work, for example, for an asteroid plummeting from the vicinity of the Moon.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

The gravitational force is expressed by

$$f=-\frac{mgR^2}{(R+h)^2}$$ so that

$$\ddot h=-\frac{gR^2}{(R+h)^2}.$$

From this,

$$\dot h\ddot h=-\frac{gR^2}{(R+h)^2}\dot h$$
and by integration, assuming a null initial speed,

$$\dot h^2=2gR^2\left(\frac1{R+h}-\frac 1{R+h_0}\right)=2gR^2\frac{h_0-h}{(R+h_0)(R+h)}.$$

Then

$$dt=\sqrt{\frac{R+h_0}{2gR^2}}\sqrt{\frac{R+h}{h_0-h}}dh,$$

that you integrate from $h_0$ to $0$.

Comment: That $m$ should be present in the very first equation, so that it disappears from the second equation.

Comment: @TonyK: you are right.

Comment: Hmm, looks like mine but still not getting result. Must be may integration skills